# Debug Mode - LINQ NullReferenceException on Collection Constructor

Tags: linq, debugging, collections, nullreferenceexception

I think I've found a bug in Visual Studio when you drag-and-drop the break-point to a different branch and you're using a certain type of LINQ query. If you place a breakpoint on the "if (x)" below and drag the executing line to the else branch, the code will fail on the initialisation/constructor for the "test2" collection.

I've used this "double from" syntax in LINQ before to do joins and I assume it's a accepted practice - not sure if there's a term for it.

Anyway can anyone else confirm this strange debug behaviour?

```
    public class TestEntity
    {
        public int TestID { get; set; }
        public string Test { get; set; }
    }

    public class Test2Entity
    {
        public int Test2ID { get; set; }
        public string Test2 { get; set; }
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            bool x = Calc();

            if (x) //breakpoint here
            {
                int y = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection<TestEntity> test = new System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection<TestEntity>();
                System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection<Test2Entity> test2 = new System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection<Test2Entity>(); // fails here

                var z = from t in test
                        from t2 in test2
                        select t.TestID;
            }
        }

        private bool Calc()
        {
            return true;
        }
```

Comment: I have not faced this error.